# how can user choose which data he want to view in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that contains 100 of rows I want that user can select how many rows in the grid he want to view (Means header and data of that header). Have you any idea. 
Example:

```
SL     NO       NAME     DATE       END DATE           SUB TOTAL             TOTAL 
==================================================================================


==================================================================================
```

User can choose he want to see only  SL NAME SUB TOTAL TOTAL in gridview and after that Grid will display data like this

```
SL            NAME                   SUB TOTAL                          TOTAL
==============================================================================



==============================================================================
```

I am binding like this

```
<data:ActiveOrdersDataSource ID="ActiveOrdersDataSourcebyCompany" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetPaged" EnablePaging="True" EnableSorting="True" EnableDeepLoad="True">
    <DeepLoadProperties Method="IncludeChildren" Recursive="False">
        <Types>
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Clients" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Companies" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Drivers" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="SalesPeople" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="ServiceTypes" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="VehicleTypes" />
            <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Zones" />
        </Types>
    </DeepLoadProperties>
    <Parameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="CompanyId" SessionField="CompanyId" Type="String" />
        <data:SqlParameter Name="WhereClause" UseParameterizedFilters ="false">
            <Filters>
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="CompanyId" ControlID="ddlCompany" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ComparisionType="Equals" />
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="AccountNumber" ControlID="ddlAccount" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ComparisionType="Equals" />
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="ServiceTypeId" ControlID="ddlService" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ComparisionType="Equals" />
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="VehicleTypeId" ControlID="ddlVehicle" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ComparisionType="Equals" />
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="StatusId" ControlID="ddlStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ComparisionType="Equals" />
                <data:ActiveOrdersFilter Column="OrderNo" ControlID="txtOrderNumber" ComparisionType="Contains" />
            </Filters>
        </data:SqlParameter> 
    </Parameters>
</data:ActiveOrdersDataSource>
```

Comment: You should really consider rephrasing your question title and body. What do you mean by "data"? Rows, columns? Do you want to display the "data" based on user permissions or do you want to let the user select what is being displayed?

Comment: Hi Alex i rephrased my question that will help you

Comment: For this, you'll need: 1. To identify the user 2. To store the user preferences 3. To conditionally render the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the visibility of columns based on user preference by setting the `Visibility` property on each column. If you're using an ObjectDataSource, you can control the number of rows by setting `PageSize`.